# Ftp class not found in lumen to transfer file

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, lumen

I am trying to transfer file through FTP . First of all I converted base64 data to blob then tried to transfer through FTP . Here my input data is base64 image. but getting **Class 'League\Flysystem\Adapter\Ftp' not found** error. Here I am sharing my code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$base_64_data = $request->get('profile_pic'); // Ex: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD.......
$dir = 'profile/';
$file_name = $dir . 'test.png';
$status = Storage::disk('ftp')->put($file_name, base64_decode($base_64_data));

dd($status);
```